# Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong with Binding in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Below I've attached snippets of my xaml & cs files. I'm trying to bind the entry boxes to the correct properties & the label is to be binded to the total property. I'm obviously going wrong somewhere I just can't put my finger on where. When using WPF I lay out my binding the same way. I've tried googling this & several videos which none seem to help my problem.

XAML

```
 <Label Text="{Binding Total}"
               TextColor="Black"
               FontSize="50"
               Grid.Column="1"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
               Grid.Row="4"
               Grid.RowSpan="1"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

        <Label Text="APR Amount"
               TextColor="Black"
               FontSize="16"
               Grid.Column="1"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
               Grid.Row="5"
               Grid.RowSpan="1"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

        <Label Text="£APR"
               TextColor="Black"
               FontSize="30"
               Grid.Column="1"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
               Grid.Row="6"
               Grid.RowSpan="1"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

         <BoxView Color="CornflowerBlue"
                CornerRadius="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                Grid.Row="7"
                Grid.RowSpan="1"   
                WidthRequest="700"
                HeightRequest="5"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Label Text="Loan Amount"
               TextColor="Black"
               FontSize="20"
               Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
               Grid.Row="9"
               Grid.RowSpan="2"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               Margin="0,0,0,0" />

        <Entry Grid.Row="9"
               Grid.Column="2"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
               Grid.RowSpan="2"
               WidthRequest="120"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="End"
               Text="{Binding loanLength}"
               Margin="0,0,45,0" />

         <Label Text="Interest Rate"
               TextColor="Black"
               FontSize="20"
               Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
               Grid.Row="11"
               Grid.RowSpan="2"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               Margin="0,0,0,0" />

        <Entry Grid.Row="11"
               Grid.RowSpan="2"
               Grid.Column="2"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
               WidthRequest="120"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="End"
               Text="{Binding intRate}"
               Margin="0,0,45,0" />

        <Label Text="Loan Length (Years)"
               TextColor="Black"
               FontSize="20"
               Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
               Grid.Row="13"
               Grid.RowSpan="2"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               Margin="0,0,0,0" />

        <Entry Grid.Row="13"
               Grid.RowSpan="2"
               Grid.Column="2"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
               WidthRequest="120"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="End"
               Text="{Binding loanLength}"
               Margin="0,0,45,0"/>
```

C#

```
  private int loanAmount { get; set; }
        public int Loan
        {
            get => loanAmount;
            set
            {

                loanAmount = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Loan");
                CalculateAPR();
            }

        }


        private int intRate { get; set; }
        public int Interest
        {
            get => intRate;
            set
            {

                intRate = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Interest");
                CalculateAPR();
            }

        }

        private int loanLength { get; set; }
        public int Length
        {
            get => loanLength;
            set
            {

                loanLength = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Length");
                CalculateAPR();
            }

        }


        private string total { get; set; }
        public string Total
        {
            get => total;
            set
            {

                total = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Total");
            }
        }



        public void CalculateAPR()
        {
            if (Interest != 0)
            {
                Total = "£" + (Loan * Length) / Interest;
            }
            else
            {
                Total = "£ -";
            }
        }
```

Comment: `Text="{Binding loanLength}"` - `loanLength` is private.  `Length` is the name of the public property.  Same applies to `intRate`.  And `loanLength` is bound to two different entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a demo to simulate your code,and it worked properly.
There are severals problems in your code:

1.We should bind a public property, for example, you can bind like this:

```
      <Entry 
           Text="{Binding Loan}"
           Margin="0,0,45,0" />
```

Instead of

```
      <Entry 
           Text="{Binding loanLength}"
           Margin="0,0,45,0" />
```

The same is true of other fields.

Replace `<Entry Text="{Binding intRate }"/>` with `<Entry Text="{Binding Interest}"/>`
and

Replace `<Entry Text="{Binding loanLength }"/>` with `<Entry Text="{Binding Length}"/>`

2.Try the following bindingContext code:

```
   <Grid >
    <Grid.BindingContext>
        <local:ViewModel></local:ViewModel>
    </Grid.BindingContext>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--other code-->

 </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks Jessie! where abouts do I put <Grid.BindingContext> & <local:ViewModel> ? after my  <Grid>? or after </Grid.RowDefinitions> ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to bind to a public property like "Length" or "Interest"
and call PropertyChanged(nameof(loanLength)); for example (with private inside)

check this if you need
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics

Comment: updated it to what you said mate, its still not changing the label

Comment: How do you set the bindingcontext for the page?

Comment: maybe the problem in binding mode 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics#the-binding-mode

Comment: I have added  <Grid BindingContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}"> to my grid in the xaml but still nothing I want it one way so when people using the app type it will calculate & show the total in the label